# Advanced DOM manipulation in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, dom

Good morning everybody,

I am currently learning Angular. I would like to know how can we achieve DOM manipulation like we used to do in JQuery but the Angular way.

For example if I want to select all elements of a type or with a specific class, loop through the array or list of matched elements and apply some treatment (after the page or view have been rendered like document ready function in JQuery).

In JQuery it would look like :

```
$('elementsTofind').each(function(index, value){
  // Apply code to each element
});
```

Thank you

Comment: not sure why you would need to do that with Angular. Why is it not being done while rendered?

Comment: Well, you need to start forgetting anything about jquery.

Comment: I am not using JQuery but I would like to know how we can achieve same result using Angular mecanism.

Comment: You don't do DOM manipulation like in jQuery. Your (seemingly theoretical) problem is based on jQuery behaviour. As mentioned above, forget completely about jQuery and come up with an actual real world problem you need to solve, and ask a corresponding question to see how it's done in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, QueryList, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('elementsTofind') elementsTofind!: QueryList<Element>;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChildren is set
    // ...
    myMethod();
    // ...
  }
  myMethod(): void {
    elementsTofind.forEach((value, index) => {
      // Apply code to each element
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kaustubh for the solution. I didn't try it yet but can I put the same logic in a directive instead of a component .ts file and put the directive on the component after ? Would it also work like that. I am asking because someone told me to never manipulate or interact with the DOM outside of e directive. Thank you

Comment: @PierreRubensMilorme I do not know the answer to that. I'd also suggest making your future questions as detailed as possible (instead of "how do I <X>?", say "how do I <X> using directives?").